# Simple static route issue on ASUS router

Tags: routing

I practice "occasional networking" i.e. I set up stuff now and again based on needs, but between projects I forget plenty :) I have a seemingly simple question about static routing that is eluding me.

I have an ASUS ac87u router for my home network. I recently set up some IP cameras on the default subnet (192.168.1.0). I want to move these to 192.168.2.0 for various reasons.

As a precursor to this change, I am looking to test with a computer plugged into one of the LAN ports on the ASUS. It is has a manually configured IP address of 192.168.2.100. Both the default gateway and DNS are configured for 192.168.1.1.

My hope was that a static route from the 192.168.2.0 subnet to my router (192.168.1.1) would do the trick. But it's not.

From the computer I can ping 192.168.1.1 just fine and, in fact, access the routers admin page. However, the static route (see below) doesn't seem to be working - I can't ping anything on the 192.168.1.0 subnet. Also, no devices on the .1.0 subnet can ping 192.168.1.200.

My status route is set up as:

Network Host / IP : 192.168.2.0
Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0
Gateway : 192.168.1.1
Interface: LAN

Any idea what I might be missing here?

Thank you

Comment: Routers, by their very nature and function have to have an interface on the same network as the devices you’re tying to communicate with. By changing the subnet of your PC you have in essence placed it on its own little network island. One in which it will not get off of without a router that has an interface on the same subnet. Unless you also plan on changing the router LAN address to be on the same network, or you have the capability to setup vLANs and multiple sub-interfaces on your router this will not work.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So is the implication that a router such as this doesn't have the ability to handle different subnets on different physical ports? If that's the case then, yes, I guess VLANs may be my next line of research. That said, I am still a little confused how the computer on 192.168.2.100 can access the router on 192.168.1.1 since it's a different subnet, no?

Comment: PS: I should add that what I am trying to achieve is reasonably straightforward, namely to separate my device into two subnets. It was my impression (though it looks like I am wrong from your response) that a device such as this could handle that scenario. I have Merlin installed on my aC87u but not clear if that opens up any specific solutions (VLANs, etc). Thank you again.

Comment: It’s not likely a home router would support this. But that doesn’t mean you need to buy a high end device either. Many cheap routers and network switches support vLANs and inter-vLAN routing. But it’s a fairly advanced topic and may require multiple vLAN capable devices across your network to implement. The simplest thing would be to have a router that supports multiple subnet interfaces. At least two, tied each one to a different physical port on the router. After which you could just use basic network switches to hook additional devices to their respective router port.

Comment: Your PC can communicate with the router because you specified the IP as the default gateway. Your computer essentially sees all other IP addresses as being off network and sends the packets to the default gateway, which happens to be your router. It’s happening at the MAC address level irregardless of the IP addresses. If Merlin supports vLANs, or more basically multiple router interfaces on different ports then it will work. One port on one subnet, the other port on the other subnet. The router will take care of the rest.

Comment: With thanks again for the excellent help, I do have one more question. If my 192.168.2.100 device can send traffic to the default gateway on 192.168.1.1 successfully, isn't the final part of the puzzle to have hosts on 192.168.2.0 know to send traffic through 1.1? Isn't that what the static route would be intended to do i.e. "I don't know how to reach addresses that are not on 192.168.2.0, but I do now the next step should be through 192.168.1.1". I know I am beating a dead horse here :) but just want to be sure I'm not missing something before dropping this idea.

Comment: What you are trying to do would require a router with  multiple LAN interfaces that are each individually configurable. The devices would be on separate physical lines and would communicate *through* the router, by means of a "rule" you would install in the router. More than just a simple modification to the routing table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very convinced that your static route is working at all. When I test such route on Linux (i.e. a route that has the host itself as gateway), it merely makes the host keep sending ARP request (for its own IP); while on the other hand, a route without a gateway would work as expected. (For the record, my Linksys EA6900 doesn't allow its LAN address to be used as a gateway for a static route.)

So I think while you have assigned `192.168.2.100` to the test computer, it also has an address in `192.168.1.0/24` assigned to it. (Or you made a typo and mistakenly assigned `192.168.1.200` instead of `192.168.2.100`, just like you did in your question.)

In fact, if your router allow you to add a subnet route without a gateway (or perhaps even better, another LAN side IP), things would have worked. (Assuming there're no firewall rules that limits LAN side forwarding.) It's totally possible to use multiple IP subnets (note that I am saying IP subnets, not VLAN or whatsoever) for devices that are connected to the same switch (consumer-grade router is also a switch at the same time), and to have certain devices in both/all subnets. It's just whether there's a point to do so depends on what you want to achieve.

If you merely want devices to be in different IP range, you can even just use a bigger subnet (e.g. `/23`). I mean, you can change the LAN side subnet mask of the router to `255.255.254.0` and retain the DHCP pool to a `/24` range within the subnet), you can then group devices with manually assigned IP to the other `/24` range. (AFAIK, you can't have `192.168.1.0/24` and `192.168.2.0/24` for that, but only like `192.168.0.0/24` and `192.168.1.0/24` or `192.168.2.0/24` and `192.168.3.0/24`, etc. You might be required to use address from the lower range for the router as well.) Note that this does not necessarily change the fact that all the devices are still in the same IP subnet (but well, for the devices with the subnet mask of `255.255.255.0`, that is, the ones have static IPs, are not in the same subnet as hosts in the lower/larger range anymore).